# Design objects with save/delete/update functionality

Tags: php, oop, model

I am using Cassandra with heavy denormalization so I cannot use some kind of universal class to delete/add/update/etc.. objects since every type of object has its own list of tables that needs to be changed.

For example to delete `User` I will need to touch 3 tables, not just one. To delete `Item` I will need to touch 7 tables, etc.. It means that logic is completely different based on object type.

## Scenario 1

User class contains only fields that I need (id, name, etc..) and static functions to find users, delete users etc..

```
<?php

class User {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    // Magic getters and setters removed to save space here

    public static function delete($id) {
        // find user by id
        // delete that user
    }
}
```

## Scenario 2

User class has everything - fields (id, name, etc..) and also functions that will delete/edit/create/etc.. that particular user

```
<?php

class User {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    // Magic getters and setters removed to save space here

    public function delete() {
        // find user by $this->id
        // delete that user
    }
}
```

Which scenario is better and maybe there is some other way to do this that is even better?

Comment: Scenerio 2 would be better imho. There's no real justification for the statics and they can be more difficult to unit test.

Comment: Scenario 2 for me is better!

Answer (score 0):

I vote #2.

The main thing is to choose one, be clear why and stick to it. Things are going to get very confusing if you mix these approaches or you are not clear about why you have chosen a particular approach.

I Scenario 2 because its clear what you are deleting, its always related to `$this`.

Also in Scenario 2 your delete method needs less validation as this validation can be offloaded to the constructor, or simple check if `$id` is set before deleting the object or database row.

In Scenario 1 though you would need to take `$id` and check that is exists before attempting to remove it in order to be sure you are actually removing something. You could also return the number of rows deleted too, which could be validation in itself too. But in the future this validation may be more complex than just checking what is being deleted.

Better to let the construction or a `load()` function deal with as much of the validation.